# SQL query to combine multiple rows from 1 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am looking for some help in trying to combine multiple rows that have a common ID into 1 row with SQL Server.  Here's an example:

```
ID  Name   Number
1   Joe    1234
1   Marie  5678
1   Ron    2222
1   Tom    4444
```

Want the query to display this:

```
ID  Name  Number  Name  Number  Name  Number  Name  Number
1   Joe   1234    Marie 5678    Ron   2222    Tom   4444
```

Comment: What should the result set show if you had another row: `1 | Jimbo | 9999|`? Seems like a very odd result you're after.

Answer (score 1):

```
with data as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by ID order by ID) as rowid
    from (
        values (1, 'Joe', 1234),
                (1, 'Marie', 5678),
                (1, 'Ron', 2222),
                (1, 'Tom', 4444)
    ) t (ID, Name, Number)
)
select t.ID, t.[1] as Name, t2.[1] as Number, t.[2] as Name, t2.[2] as Number, 
             t.[3] as Name, t2.[3] as Number, t.[4] as Name, t2.[4] as Number
from (
    select ID, Name, rowid
    from data
) d pivot (min(Name) for rowid in ([1], [2], [3], [4])) t
inner join (
    select ID, Number, rowid
    from data
) d2 pivot (min(Number) for rowid in ([1], [2], [3], [4])) t2 on t.ID = t2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest applying both the UNPIVOT and the PIVOT functions to the get the result.  The UNPIVOT will convert your `name` and `number` columns into multiple rows, then you will apply the PIVOT function to convert that back into columns:

```
select *
from
(
  select id,
    col+'_'+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col,
    value
  from
  (
    select id, name, cast(number as varchar(10)) number,
      row_number() over(partition by id order by number) rn
    from yt
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (name, number)
  ) unpiv
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (name_1, number_1, name_2, number_2,
              name_3, number_3, name_4, number_4)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bee00/5). This gives a result:

```
| ID | NAME_1 | NUMBER_1 | NAME_2 | NUMBER_2 | NAME_3 | NUMBER_3 | NAME_4 | NUMBER_4 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |    Joe |     1234 |    Ron |     2222 |    Tom |     4444 |  Marie |     5678 |
```